# " context is incorrect " while using node_wrangle with Python API

Tags: python, texturing, node-editor

i do this in the python colsole and got a error

```
bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled(filepath="F:\\texture\\paper\\PaperFolded004_6k\\PaperFolded004_NRM_6K.jpg", 
directory="F:\\texture\\paper纸\\PaperFolded004_6k\\", 
files=[{"name":"PaperFolded004_NRM_6K.jpg", "name":"PaperFolded004_NRM_6K.jpg"}, {"name":"PaperFolded004_REFL_6K.jpg", "name":"PaperFolded004_REFL_6K.jpg"}, {"name":"PaperFolded004_DISP16_6K.tif", "name":"PaperFolded004_DISP16_6K.tif"}, {"name":"PaperFolded004_GLOSS_6K.jpg", "name":"PaperFolded004_GLOSS_6K.jpg"}, {"name":"PaperFolded004_DISP_6K.jpg", "name":"PaperFolded004_DISP_6K.jpg"}, {"name":"PaperFolded004_COL_VAR1_6K.jpg", "name":"PaperFolded004_COL_VAR1_6K.jpg"}, {"name":"PaperFolded004_COL_VAR2_6K.jpg", "name":"PaperFolded004_COL_VAR2_6K.jpg"}], relative_path=True)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Program\Blender\3.5\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

but the code is copyed from the log ,i dont know what's wrong

### the image

[image]

Comment: try `bpy.ops.node.nw_add_textures_for_principled("INVOKE_DEFAULT")`